# doesn't print console log

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Here I am trying to display the value of checkbox in console but it doesn't.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="id_price" value="1" onclick="display_img()">Under £200<br>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="id_price" value="2" > £250-£300<br>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="id_price" value="3" > £300-£450<br>
```

And Js code is

```
function display_img(){
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id_price").each(function(){
        if($(this).is("checked")){
            var check=document.getElementById("id_price").value;
            console.log(check);
        }
    });
});
```

}

Comment: Id is meant to be UNIQUE,   you should use class instead.

Comment: @Xiaoerge you're correct but that doesn't necessarily mean it shouldn't display it. in this case, it should display the value of the first id.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw,  I said a comment not an answer.  Or else it'll be in the answers.

Comment: @Xiaoerge it doesn't display anything. :(

Answer (score 2):

There were a few errors in your code such as:

- You used multiple id's. An id should be unique for each element
- You only used onclick="" on one of the elements
- It should be `$(this).is(":checked")`

Below is the edited working JavaScript & HTML.

```js
function display_img() {
  $(".id_price").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      var check = $(this).val();
      console.log(check);
    }
  });
};

$(".id_price").change(display_img);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="id_price" value="1">Under £200
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="id_price" value="2"> £250-£300<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="id_price" value="3"> £300-£450<br>
```

Comment: Thanks :) appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Selector must be `:selector`, then work well. http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

```
function display_img() {
    $("#id_price").each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            var check = document.getElementById("id_price").value;
            console.log(check);
        }
    });
}
```

Or

```
$(this).attr('checked') // 1.6 -
$(this).prop('checked') // 1.6 +
```

Comment: Yea that little mistake can ruin the whole program. Thnx though i figured out.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using jQuery.. your code should be like this, and make sure to use css class instead of same id.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".id_price").each(function(){
        _this = $(this);
        if(_this.is("checked")){            
            console.log(_this.val());
        }
    });
});
```